# Excel output from an Access query to include an excel formula in the cell

Tags: excel, output

I have a database query the results that are saved to an Excel file. Once there, I need to add a column and insert formula to do make it an interactive worksheet.

Is there a way of having the formula created in the data base output? Note that I do not want the results entered. I want the Excel formula to be in the cell. Example in one cell I enter `=IFERROR(TODAY()-I14+1,0)` the results in the Excel spreadsheet change base on the date the information is viewed.

Answer (score 0):

use the cell formula property to dynamically add formula:

```
Range("A1").Formula = "=text(now(),""mmm dd yyyy"")"
```

ref:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx